# Shift values in data frame within the same column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, shift

I have a data frame with data from several years and few variables (ID, Var1,2,3). I would like to create a new df which will have replace the values in Var1 and Var2 with those in the previous year ordered by vrr ID. The Var 3 remains unchanged.

```
df_input <- data.frame( YEAR = c("1999", "1999", "1999","1999","2000","2000", "2000", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001"),
                  ID=c("ID1", "ID2","ID3", "ID4","ID1", "ID2","ID3", "ID4", "ID1", "ID2","ID3", "ID4"),
                  Var1 =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), 
                  Var2 = c(11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,101,111,121),
                  Var3 = sample(x = 101:200, size =12)
)
```

This should be the output after the change

```
df_out <- data.frame( YEAR = c("1999", "1999", "1999","1999","2000","2000", "2000", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001"),
                  ID=c("ID1", "ID2","ID3", "ID4","ID1", "ID2","ID3", "ID4", "ID1", "ID2","ID3", "ID4"),

                  Var1 =c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4, 5,6,7,8), 
                  Var2 = c(11,21,31,41,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81),
                  Var3 = sample(x = 101:200, size =12)
)
```

Any help on this?
Thank you

Comment: Can you explain the logic of changes in `Var1` and `Var2`? Why only values corresponding to `2001` get affected? And, here `Var3` does get changed. perhaps you meant to set a seed.

Comment: Does years have gaps? Is there always only 1 record for `YEAR` per `ID`?

Comment: I need to do a separate analysis for each year with: Year, ID, Var1, Var2 and Var4 as variables. I need  to replace the values of Var1, Var2 with those  from previous year. In this case,  Var1 in 2000 (5,6,7,8) should be replaced with the one from 1999 (1,2,3,4) and Var2 in 2000  (51,61,71,81) should be replaced with the Values from 1999  (11,21,31,41).  For 2001 I follow the same logic by replacing the values for Var1 and Var2  with the corresponding values from previous year, 2000.  The values for Var3 should remain unafected. Years do not have gaps and there is one record for year and ID.